# How can I insert row for each existing id into same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `users_settings` where I store settings for each user. In the following table you can see there are settings for two users `78` and `79`.

[image]

Now I want to add one more row each two users, `key = 'app_reminder'`. So is there any way to do it by query or I will have to use php script for it.

I would appreciate if someone guide me about it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into users_settings (user_id, key)
    select distinct user_id, 'app_reminder'
    from users_settings;
```

Note:  This assumes that `id` is assigned automatically.

If you specifically only want this for those two users, you could add `where user_id in (78, 79)` or use:

```
insert into users_settings (user_id, key)
    select uuser_id, 'app_reminder'
    from (select 78 as user_id union all select 79) u;
```

Comment: thanks, no 78 and 79 are just for example, I need to do it for thousands of users

Comment: @ScriptLover . . . I added that just in case.  The first query should do what you want.

Comment: +1 . It is working fine, i just check it. But I don't see `VALUES` keyword in this insert query, so this is new thing for me. I would appreciate you if you kindly add little bit explanation for the query so in this I and future beginners would be able to understand that how this query is working

Comment: @ScriptLover . . . Actually, `VALUES()` is really superfluous.  `INSERT . . . SELECT` is more powerful and can do what `INSERT . . . VALUES` does.

Comment: Thank you so much, just one more thing please, can I add where clause `SELECT DISTINCT user_id, 'app_reminder' WHERE `key` != 'app_reminder'` - definitely it is accepted answer

Comment: @ScriptLover . . . No.  If you want to prevent adding the status twice, then I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.  This question doesn't even hint at that requirement.

Comment: Sure, I understand it. Thank you

Comment: Here is new question I have posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62303967/how-to-check-existing-record-before-inserting-record-for-each-user-into-same-tab