# How to check existing record before inserting record for each user into same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table where I wanted to store one more key for each user, following is the table,

[image]

I was trying to add `app_reminder` for each existing users. I did it by following

```
insert into users_settings (user_id, key)
    select distinct user_id, 'app_reminder'
    from users_settings;
```

Now I want to add where clause

`SELECT DISTINCT user_id, 'app_reminder' WHERE key != 'app_reminder'`

for preventing duplicate entries. I tried above one but it does not working.

Can someone kindly guide me about it, I would appreciate.

Thank you

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Do you get an error? Unexpected results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method simply uses conditional aggregation:

```
insert into users_settings (user_id, key)
    select user_id, 'app_reminder'
    from users_settings
    group by user_id
    having sum(key = 'app_reminder') = 0;
```

You might want a more generic solution.  If you want to ensure that user/key pairs are never duplicated, then create a unique constraint or index on those columns:

```
alter table users_settings add constraint unq_users_settings_user_id_key
    unique (user_id, key);
```

Then, you can skip inserting the rows using `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into users_settings (user_id, key)
    select distinct user_id, 'app_reminder'
    from users_settings
    on duplicate key update user_id = values(user_id);
```

The `update` does nothing, because the value is the same.  MySQL skips doing the insert and does not return an error.

Comment: It is working fine, thanks. Just great sql skill, just curious how to become expert